# Cordova/Phonegap facebook plugin An active access token must be used to query information

Tags: android, facebook, cordova, oauth

I am using https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin to connect my cordova Android app to Facebook.
I can login with:

    `facebookConnectPlugin.login(["email"],
    fbLoginSuccess,
    function (error) { alert("ERROR:" + JSON.stringify(error)); }
    );`
, logout even call `facebookConnectPlugin.getLoginStatus` and get:

- userID
- accessToken
- expiresIn
- sig
- status

but when `FB.api('/me', function(response){...})` is called, I receive 
    `{error:
        { 
        message: An active access token must be used to query information about the current user,
        type: OAuthException,
        code: 2500
        }
    }`
Also this only happens when the app is built, not tested in browser.

Answer (score 0):

Solved issue by manually giving `FB.api`call a token with:

`FB.api('/me?access_token='+userdata.authResponse.accessToken, function(response) {...`
 
where `userdata` is the response of `facebookConnectPlugin.getLoginStatus`
I just don't understand why doesn't it provide token automatically in android app like it does in browser.

Answer (score 0):

Send the access token and the data retrieving fields with the apiString

```
  const fields = ['email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'gender', 'birthday', 'picture.type(large)'];
  const apiString = `me?access_token=${accessToken}&fields=${fields.join(',')}`;
```